# converting for and if statements to list comprehensions in python

Tags: list, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop, list-comprehension

I'm trying to incorporate list comprehensions in my code, for ease of understanding's and efficiency's sake.

My code is this:

```
for tblock in jdata['network']['tcp']:
    if not [tblock['dst'], tblock['dport']] in test:
        test.append([tblock['dst'], tblock['dport']])
        test = [ip for ip in test if not ip[0].startswith(fil2)]
```

The error I am getting is on the test.append part. Below is just a cobbled together attempt, as I dont know how to bring in the test.append portion.

```
test = [tblock for tblock in jdata['network']['tcp'] if not [tblock['dst'], tblock['dport']] in test if test > 0  test.append([tblock['dst'], tblock['dport']])]

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

For context, `fil2` is a list of IP's that filters against the information. I can provide test data if anyone needs it.

Comment: OK, so you know how to convert part of the code into a list comprehension. What is the problem when converting the rest of it?

Comment: Your original code *replaces* `test` with a new list, after appending to the old. Surely that's not the idea?

Comment: There's a lot of ways to make that code more efficient - but making it into a list comp is the least of them.  You're looking at ~1% improvements, whereas switching `test` to a `set` could cut your runtime by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Great comments, i'll look into using set!

Comment: What I didnt mention is that I would like to preserve duplicates, and I think set would strip me of that ability. I run through 300-3000 hashes and strip out from each of the hashes i request info on.  Each time something is seen it becomes more useful to me and more important. If the advice of the community is that making a list  comprehension will not speed up this process, I can accept that.

Comment: Well your current code *doesn't* preserve duplicates - the `if not [tblock['dst'], tblock['dport']] in test:` line makes sure (inefficiently) that no duplicates happen.

Comment: Another section inserts the hash, which as you said, would be meaningless to try to avoid duplicates. Its all rough,  but ill get there! Would it be more efficient to reduce the loops and try to make each iteration through the loop more and more productive? This does 300 requests to an api, i suppose it can only be so fast.